# drools score using multiple planning entities

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm attempting to develop a Drools score for OptaPlanner to maximize the creation of similar paired transportation runs.

The planning entity is a run - 500 of these:

- runID
- amPmIndicator - contains AM or PM
- location

The planning variable contains paired run possibilities - 12,000 of these:

- runID1
- location1
- runID2
- location2
- amPmIndicator

A higher ranking score is used to maximize paired runs using runID and that rule works fine because it resolves to the specific runID.

I need to develop a lower ranking rule that maximizes a balanced number of paired locations in the AM and PM.  So two locations that are paired in the AM should be paired in the same locations in the PM.

How can a Drools score be configured to accomplish this?  It seems that it needs to accumulate a count of the planning variable for the AM that are assigned to two planning entities, and then compare with the count of similar PM planning variables with the same locations as the AM planning entity.

Or is there a better way to model this?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I believe that my question is more of one of DRL language capabilities and how to perform the aggregation.
Here's the rule that I wrote, but it only ensures that only one pair exists in the PM.

```
// Attempts to make certain that a morning pairing at a Location level exists in the morning and afternoon 
// This rule should attempt to count Location pairs in AM and PM rule
"matchedLocationsAmToPm"
        when
            Run(amPm == "AM" && earlyLate == "EARLY", $amPair : pair, $earlyLocationId : LocationId)
            Run(amPm == "AM" &&  earlyLate == "LATE" && pair == $amPair, $lateLocationId : LocationId)
            Run(amPm == "PM" &&  earlyLate == "EARLY" && LocationId == $earlyLocationId, $pmPair : pair)
            not Run(amPm == "PM" &&  earlyLate == "LATE" && LocationId == $lateLocationId && pair == $pmPair)
        then
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 6.1 docs, look for "fairness / load balacing score constraints". Also so [see this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB2CxfLhHG4) about it.

Because paired runs are a soft constraints (apparently), I wouldn't change your model. (If they were hard constraints, one could argue for a model to make a planning entity have 2 `previousStandstill` planning variables, but even then I might not recommend it.)

Comment: I added a clarification and sample code to the original question above.

Comment: Sigh. See the first sentence of my answer: docs = clarification, video = name of example in optplanner examples.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I understand now and I will try this solution.  It takes me a while to think this way. Your patience is greatly appreciated.